# Facebook shows two separate login dialogs and fails login

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.x

I am logging into facebook on Android using `facebook android sdk (4.7.0)`. Most of the time it shows following dialog and works fine.

[image: working dialog]

But sometimes it shows the following dialog and login **does not work.**

[image: dialog not working]

What are possibilites for failed login in this case? I am testing it on `android (5.1.1)`.

```
  facebookButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile, email, user_birthday"));
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

        facebookButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                        loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                        new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(
                                    JSONObject object,
                                    GraphResponse response) {
                                // Application code
                                try {
                                    fbid = object.getString("id");
                                    fbfirst_name = object.getString("first_name");
                                    fblast_name = object.getString("last_name");
                                    fbemail = object.getString("email");
                                    new FBRegistrationService().execute();

                                } catch (Exception ex) {
                                    ex.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,gender,birthday,first_name,last_name");
                request.setParameters(parameters);
                request.executeAsync();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
            }
        });
```

> **Update**: I am also getting these logs.

```
"Blink deferred a task in order to make scrolling smoother. Your timer and network tasks should take less than 50ms to run to avoid this. Please see https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/profile/evaluate-performance/rail and https://crbug.com/574343#c40 for more information.", source: https://m.facebook.com/login.php?skip_api_login=1&api_key=350893648453711&signed_next=1&next=https%3A%2F%2Fm.facebook.com%2Fv2
```

Comment: can you post the code where you are trying to prompt for facebook login?

Comment: done. have a look ...

Comment: code is fine,make sure that you are not calling this method somewhere or check for condition like is the session is opened? .There will be no issue with the Facebook SDK or versions.You will get solution by debugging,or else post the complete activity.